# Capybara - how to see if a dropdown element is selected?

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver, capybara, html-select

My HTML is

```
<select id="auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership" name="auto_policy[autos_attributes][0][ownership]">
  <option value="Owned">Owned</option>
  <option value="Financed">Financed</option>
  <option value="Leased" selected="selected">Leased</option></select>
```

and I can select up to

```
find('select#auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership option[value="Leased"]')
```

correctly, but how do I see if it has been checked?

I tried

```
find('select#auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership option[value="Leased" selected="selected"]')
```

but I get

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: 
An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I had hopes for

```
'select#auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership option[value="Leased"], selected')).to be
```

but I get a false positive as

```
'select#auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership option[value="Owned"], selected')).to be
```

returns true, even though I have selected Leased with

```
select 'Leased', from: 'auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership'
```

which I can see working in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`be_selected` matcher](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/d5ce08812a085947c870db3f0ac1630303e890b0/lib/capybara/spec/session/node_spec.rb#L208):

```
expect(@session.find('select#auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership option[value="Leased"]')).to be_selected
```

Answer (score 1):

One option was

```
expect(has_select?('auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership', selected: 'Leased')).to be true
```

Comment: but I prefer alecxe as be_selected is more descriptive especially when it fails (when it counts!)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the capybara have_select matcher is designed for

```
expect(page).to have_select('auto_policy_autos_attributes_0_ownership', selected: 'Leased')
```

which describes what you're checking for -- a specific select element with a specifically selected option, and provides for a nice error message when failure happens.

If you really want to stick with the predicate matcher you could also do

```
expect(find(:option, 'Leased')).to be_selected
```

although that option could be in any select on the page unless you used a within block or scoped the find to a specific select.